# Wondering that "git pull" to get latest for whole repo or just current folder?

Tags: git

I don't know if the command will 'pull' new changes for current working folder or will apply for the whole local git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pull` command will fetch and merge the new commits of the remote branch (by default master if not otherwise specified) and therefore works on the scope of the repo

Comment: It will not pull changes from branches other than master.

Answer (score 1):

It will pull the new changes for whole git Repository..